# Populating List<Object> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file like this:

```
City|Country|Phone Number
Name
City|Country|Phone Number
Name
City|Country|Phone Number
Name
```

and so on...

I have made a class as:

```
class Person
{
string city, country, phone, name;
}
```

After reading this big file, I want to make a List and place all the values in their respective fields.

**My work so far**

```
List<PersonObj> objectsList = new List<PersonObj>();

string[] peopleFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

var oddLines = peopleFile.Where((src, index) => index % 2 != 0);
var evenLines = peopleFile.Where((src, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

and its successfully retrieving address and name lines separately in `oddLines` and `evenLines` respectively.

**What I Want**

I should have objectsList populated using LINQ rather than populating them one by one using loop

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "in one line"?

Comment: @BrianMains Oh I mean directly using LINQ. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
var people = File.ReadLines(fileName)
    .Select((l,i) => new { Line = l.Split('|'), LineNo = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.LineNo/2)
    .Select(grp => new Person
         {
             city = grp.First().Line[0],
             country = grp.First().Line.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
             phone = grp.First().Line.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault(),
             name = grp.Last().Line[0]
         })
    .ToList();
```

Basically you use the overload of `Select` that gives you the index and that will allow you to group by the line number so you get groups of the first 2 lines, the next 2 lines and so on.  Then just pull from the first or last line in the group (there should only be 2) and the index of the array from doing the split.

Note that this will give incorrect results if the file doesn't match the format, such as the `name` and `city` being the same for the last entry if the file has an odd number of lines or the `country` or `phone` being null if the odd lines do not have at least two pipe characters.

Also I used `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` to avoid an unneeded intermediate array being created.

Comment: Its giving error on use of indexing. Error reads as: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Anonymous Type#1'

Comment: @TalhaIrfan My bad, I've fixed that now by referencing the `Line`  property of the anonymous class I create.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Its giving me error (index out of bounds). I suspect its due to some records don't having any value (number of | is although same in all records). Can you please guide?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Well if you have lines that should have "city | country | phone", but instead have something like "city | country" then you'll need to add guards by doing something like `country = grp.First().Line.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` instead to set it to `null` when there are not enough pipes on the line.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats what I needed. It not only works but I learnt couple of new things too

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I assume that `evenLines` contains the cities etc. and `oddLines` the names.

```
var persons = oddLines.Zip(
    evenLines.Select(line => line.Split('|')),
    (name, data) => new Person {name = name, city = data[0], country = data[1], phone = data[2]});
```

`Zip` combines each line of `oddLines` with the corresponding line of `evenLines`. This second line is split by `|` and for each combination a new `Person` object is generated and filled with its data.

Of course there should be a little more error handling as this may throw exceptions if there are values missing in your file.

Answer (score 1):

For better separation of concern, you could first combine the two results in `oddLines` and `evenLines` to create a complete `string`:

```
var lines = from o in oddLines
            from ev in evenLines
            select o + "|" + ev;
```

and then use double `LINQ` `Select`:

```
objectsList = lines.Select(x => x.Split('|'))
    .Select(y => new PersonObj() {
        city = y[0],
        country = y[1],
        phone = y[2],
        name = y[3],
    }).ToList();
```

The first `Select` will be used to split each row in the file to `string[]` with 4 elements and the second `Select` is used to create `PersonObj` item from them.

Note that you have to make your fields (`city, country, phone, name`) to `public` rather than `private` to do this.

Comment: The 'name' is on a different line, so this isn't going to work.

Comment: @juharr you are right, answer updated...

Comment: @Ian Thanks Ian. Interesting approach: uses very basic LINQ.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan ah yes, to keep things simple. :) once you are better at using `LINQ`, you might be easily understand juharr's answer though, which is more complex and truly one-liner. The emphasize on my approach is the step is clear.

Comment: Thank you! Its easy to understand as I am still beginner at LINQ and understanding its syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LINQ way:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");

        List<Person> people =
            lines
                .Select((line, index) =>
                    new
                    {
                        Index = index / 2,
                        RawData = line
                    }
                )
                .GroupBy(obj => obj.Index)
                .Select(group =>
                    {
                        var rawPerson = group.ToArray();

                        string name = rawPerson[1].RawData;
                        string[] rawDetails = rawPerson[0].RawData.Split('|');

                        return
                            new Person()
                            {
                                Name = name,
                                City = rawDetails[0],
                                Country = rawDetails[1],
                                PhoneNumber = rawDetails[2]
                            };
                    }
                )
                .ToList();
    }
}
```